# How to cast my panel to access the class method to return an object?

Tags: java, swing, casting

So I am writing a program for  GUI and I'm stuck on how to cast a panel that I created through a method of another class and passed back to another class. Essentially, I have quite a bit of class and methods to create similar objects to put on multiple panels (also created through methods). Now I want to access each of the buttons that I created on each of the different panels.

So in this `makeComponents` class, I made a JSlider object.

```
    class makeComponents implements ActionListener {
        private JPanel dimPanel;
        private JSlider brightness;

        public makeComponents() {

        }
        ...
        public JPanel DimSlider(int num) {
            dimPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
                @Override
                public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                    Dimension max = super.getMaximumSize();
                    max.height = getPreferredSize().height;
                    return max;
                 }
            };
            ...
            brightness = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 50);
            dimPanel.add(brightness);
            ...
            return dimPanel;
        }
        ...
        public JSlider passBrightnessfromDimSlider() {
            return brightness;
        }
    }
```

In another method in another class, `createCPanel`, I called the DimSlider method to create a `dimPanel` to add to this container panel. This is where I am getting the java.lang.ClassCastException: makeComponents$1 cannot be cast to makeComponents. However, removing this will not work also.

```
    class lightPanel extends JPanel {
        private JPanel dimPanel1;
        private JSlider dimmer1;

        public lightPanel(int room_num) {
            ...
            dimPanel1 = new makeComponents.DimSlider(1);
            dimmer1 = ((makeComponents) dimPanel1).passBrightnessfromDimSlider();
            ...
        }
        public JSlider passDimmer1() {
            return dimmer1;
        }
```

In the above, I tried to pass the particular JSlider `brightness` created for dimPanel1. Then in the below class is another container panel that will hold this panel along with another one.

```
    class createCPanel extends JPanel {
        private JPanel lightPanel;
        private JSlider brightSlider1;
        ...
        public createCPanel(int num) {
            ...
            lightPanel = new lightPanel(num);
            brightSlider1 = ((lightPanel) lightPanel).passDimmer1();
            ...
        }

        public JSlider getbrightSlider1() {
            return brightSlider1;
        }

    }
```

Then I have ANOTHER panel that holds everything together! And this is where I try to access each particular JSlider for all the different ones that I created via `DimSlider` method.

```
    class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
        private JPanel rooma;

        public Panel() {
            rooma = new createCPanel(1);
            ...
            ((createCPanel) rooma).getbrightSlider1().addChangeListener(...);
        }
    }
```

So there are a lot of different components on these different panels, all of which have different functions and I need to reference each specific one in that particular panel. However, I am getting ClassCastException in the `lightPanel` method. Do anyone have any other ideas on how to fix this or suggest a better way of accessing these components?

P.S. Ideally, I would not want to put everything under one class for organization's sake. I have so many methods, but I guess if that is the only option then I have no choice.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see where `dimPanel` (in `makeComponents`) is assigned to anything.  I'm sure it is, somewhere, but in the code you didn't include.  It might help if we see it.

Comment: Oh, `dimPanel` in `makeComponents` is just a new JPanel with `GridBagLayout`. It is used in the `DimSlider` method in `makeComponents` to contain all the slider and other buttons/labels. In `lightPanel`, the `DimSlider` method is called to create that DimSlider panel and passed back to the panel that I declared in `lightPanel`.

Comment: I just added it into the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public lightPanel(int room_num) {
    ...
    dimPanel1 = new makeComponents.DimSlider(1);
    dimmer1 = ((makeComponents) dimPanel1).passBrightnessfromDimSlider();
    ...
}
```

`dimPanel1` is a JPanel. By saying `(makeComponents)dimPanel1` you are basically trying to turn a JPanel in to a makeComponents which can't be done.

When you do this:

```
JPanel panel = new makeComponents().DimSlider(1);
```

That `makeComponents` you've created is only used to call the method `DimSlider` on it and is immediately discarded. There is no way to recall it.

To literally do what you are wanting to do in your own code what you need to do is this:

```
public lightPanel(int room_num) {
    ...
    makeComponents factory = new makeComponents();
    dimPanel1 = factory.DimSlider(1);
    dimmer1 = factory.passBrightnessfromDimSlider();
    ...
}
```

But... don't create your GUI this way. It's bizarre and messy.

```
// can you spot the error?

public lightPanel(int room_num) {
    ...
    makeComponents factory = new makeComponents();
    dimmer1 = factory.passBrightnessfromDimSlider();
    dimPanel1 = factory.DimSlider(1);
    ...
}
```

Just do this:

```
class LightPanel extends JPanel {
    private JPanel dimPanel;
    private JSlider dimmer;

    public LightPanel(int roomNum) {
        ...

        dimPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                Dimension max = super.getMaximumSize();
                max.height = getPreferredSize().height;
                return max;
             }
        };
        ...

        dimmer = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 50);
        dimPanel.add(dimmer);

        ...
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
class DimPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JSlider brightness;

    public DimPanel() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        ...
        brightness = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 50);
        add(brightness);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        Dimension max = super.getMaximumSize();
        max.height = getPreferredSize().height;
        return max;
    }

    public int getBrightness() {
        return brightness.getValue();
    }
}
```